# cant use locally hosted video on react app

Tags: reactjs, video

i am using a video as a background in react  and after the video loads the server stops and i get this message
i tried 2 different libraries to have a playeer and the html tag for videos i get the same message over and over
there is no syntax error on the actual tag because changing the url with a youtube video works perfectly fine

````
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter
    at FsReadStream.close (C:x
\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:2047:17)
    at FsReadStream._destroy (C:\x\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:2032:10)
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:109:10)
    at class_1.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:71:5)     
    at class_1.<anonymous> (C:\x\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:1962:22)
    at class_1.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1344:12)   
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on class_1 instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)        
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)   
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`npm install memefs` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some node package was missing after installing `npm i memfs` works fine now.